# Javascript XMLHttpRequest - obtain response time

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

How do I retrieve the response time for a request like this..

```
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the time before the request, get the time after the request finishes, and subtract the two to get the difference:

```js
const before = new Date();
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    const now = new Date();
    const diff = now - before;
    console.log("Took " + diff + " milliseconds");
  }
};
```